# Is there a way to solve this problem by using .forEach or .map instead of for-loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to write a function that converts array elements within an array into objects. Although I've figured out a way to solve the problem by using `for-loop`, I'm just wondering **if there's more concise way to write up the solution by using methods such as `forEach` or `map`**.

The problem is...

```
var array: [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'],
    ['lastName', 'Blow'],
    ['age', 42],
    ['role', 'clerk']
  ],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['role', 'manager']
  ]
];
```

I need to convert the above array into something like this.

```
[
  { firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role: 'clerk' },
  { firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins', age: 36, role: 'manager' }
];
```

The following is the code I've come up with by using a `for-loop`.

```
function transformEmployeeData(array)
{  
  var output = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  {
    var obj = {};

    for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
    {
      obj[array[i][j][0]] = array[i][j][1];
    }

    output.push(obj);
  }

  return output;
}
```

Like I have mentioned above, it will be great if there's another way to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't see any reason to do it another way if this way works well for you. If anything, your code right now is more readable than it would be using `.map()` or `.forEach()`. Is there a reason why you would want to do it another way?

Comment: Whenever you create an empty array, and iterate over something and add it to the array, you should probably use Array#map, but if your code works, it's not a good fit for this forum. Maybe https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Another suggestion, create a function that converts each line of you array into an object.

Comment: I just started learning programming and learned about methods related to arrays recently. I just wanted apply what I've learned, but it didn't work out too well after hours of trying. I will avoid this kind of question in the the future. Thank you for your comments!

Comment: There are enough answers here... I'd go with map reducer because you might have to reduce, also what happens if the array has the same key in separate indexes, reduce to me sounds correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some near future maybe you could use [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries). It is supported on some browsers version right now: [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility):

```js
var arr = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'],
    ['lastName', 'Blow'],
    ['age', 42],
    ['role', 'clerk']
  ],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['role', 'manager']
  ]
];

console.log(arr.map(Object.fromEntries));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could map new objects by mapping the properties and join all properties to a single objects.

```js
var data = [[['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']], [['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]],
    result = data.map(a => Object.assign(...a.map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }))));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using map and reduce.

```js
  var array = [
  [['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['role', 'manager']
  ]
    ];

    var transformed = array.map(a=> a.reduce((c, p) => {c[p[0]] = p[1]; return c;},{}));
    console.log(transformed);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and `reduce` in tandem (map each element to the result of the reduce function, which transforms each element into a key/value pair):

```js
var array=[[['firstName','Joe'],['lastName','Blow'],['age',42],['role','clerk']],[['firstName','Mary'],['lastName','Jenkins'],['age',36],['role','manager']]];

const result = array.map(e => 
  e.reduce((a, [k, v]) => ((a[k] = v) || 1) && a, {}))
;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using map and forEach

```js
var array = [
  [['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['role', 'manager']
  ]
    ];

console.log(array.map(val => {
  const result = {}
  val.forEach(v => {
    result[v[0]] = v[1]
  })
  return result
}))
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ROWmEX

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do it in one line.

```js
var array = [
  [['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['role', 'manager']
  ]
    ];

const transformed = array.map(upperArr => upperArr.reduce((acc, itemArr) => { acc[itemArr[0]] = itemArr[1]; return acc;}, {}));
console.log(transformed);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function with map and forEach:

```
function transformEmployeeData(array) {  
  return array.map(toObject => {
    const obj = {};
    toObject.forEach(([key, value]) => {
      obj[key] = value;
    });
    return obj;
  });
};
```

```js
var array = [
  [['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['role', 'manager']
  ]
];
    
function transformEmployeeData(array) {  
  return array.map(toObject => {
    const obj = {};
    toObject.forEach(([key, value]) => {
      obj[key] = value;
    });
    return obj;
  });
};

console.log(transformEmployeeData(array));
```